# Turning a Binary Tree to a sorted array

Tags: java, sorting, binary-search-tree

Is there a way to turn a Binary to a sorted array without having to traverse the tree for every array index?

```
Node root;
Node runner;
int current_smallest;

void findsmallest(Node root){
    //Pre-order traversal
    if(root == null){
        return;
    }else{
        runner = root;
        if(current_smallest == null){
            current_smallest = runner.element;
        }else{
            if(current_smallest > runner.element){
            current_smallest = runner.element;
            }
        }
        findsmallest(runner.left);
        findsmallest(runner.right);
    }   
}

void fill_array( int [] array ){

    for(int i =0; i < array.length(); i++){
        findsmallest(root);
        array[i] = current_smallest;
    }
}
```

As you can see this can be take a long time if there are a lot of nodes in the tree.
Btw, I forgot to show that the whole tree would have to be traversed at the start to get the length of the array.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, you can do that: run an [*in-order traversal*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order) of the tree, keep the current position of the array, and store the node's value at the then-current position of the array.

You can do in-order traversal recursively, or you can do it with a stack data structure. If you want to do it recursively, you can do this:

```
int fill_array(Node root, int [] array, int pos) {
    if (root.left != null) {
        pos = fill_array(root.left, array, pos);
    }
    array[pos++] = root.element;
    if (root.right != null) {
        pos = fill_array(root.right, array, pos);
    }
    return pos; // return the last position filled in by this invocation
}
```

Note that in order for the above recursive procedure to work, the caller must allocate enough space in the `array` passed into the function.

Comment: I think this would not work if tree is not BST. OP asks for binary tree rather than binary search tree. Your solution with in order traversal will work only for BST and not regular binary tree. Only way to do this is to do a tree traversal (you can pick any tree traversal) and store elements in array and then sort the array. This will be O(nlogn). Please correct me if I missed anything here or if my approach is not correct.

Comment: @CodeHunter The author referred to it as "a Binary Tree" in the title, but then called it "a Binary" in the post, so I don't think it's likely they were aware of the distinction between a binary tree vs a binary search tree. I think this answer safely assumes they meant 'binary search tree'.

Answer (score 5):

A binary tree can be represented in an array; if this were the case, all you would need to do is sort the array.

Here's some more info on representing the tree in the array:  [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Arrays)

This is not necessarily the most space-efficient representation; the "nodes with references" representation may waste less space.

Answer (score 5):

What you want is an in-order traversal, which is generally implemented recursively like:

- Traverse left subtree.
- Handle this node (ie. insert as the next element in your array)
- Traverse right subtree.

Comment: I think this would not work if tree is not BST. OP asks for binary tree rather than binary search tree. Your solution with in order traversal will work only for BST and not regular binary tree. Only way to do this is to do a tree traversal (you can pick any tree traversal) and store elements in array and then sort the array. This will be O(nlogn). Please correct me if I missed anything here or if my approach is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is java code for same:

int[] result = new int[9];
fillArray(tree, result, 0);

public int fillArray(Tree tree, int[] result, int index) {
        if (tree.left != null) {
            index = fillArray(tree.left, result, index);
        }
        result[index++] = tree.val;

        if (tree.right != null) {
            index = fillArray(tree.right, result, index);
        }

   return index;
}
```