# Algorithm to combine two binary search trees in linear time

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

Given two binary search trees, is there an algorithm to combine them into a single binary search tree with linear time complexity?

I thought about putting the elements of the second tree into the first tree one by one but failed to achieve it in linear time complexity.

Answer (score 4):

If the resulting tree can be **any** binary search tree, you can do just sort the elements of the 2 trees, and create a BST which is just a sort linked list of the elements.
One way of doing so is:

1. Perform in-order traversal on each BST and put the result in an array, as the trees are BST's it's easy to prove that each array is sorted. (`O(n)` time)
2. Merge the sorted arrays into 1 sorted array using `merge` procedure from merge-sort (`O(n)` time)
3. Create a linked list of the resulting array, which also happens to be a BST (`O(n)` time)
4. return the head of the linked list.

Answer (score 1):

We know that if we have a sorted array, we can create the binary search tree in `Theta(n)`. Also, we know that how to merge two sorted arrays (using merge procedure in the merge-sort in `Theta(n)`). Now, Just create two sorted list from the current binary trees (see [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16180615/3768871)) and merging them (see the `merge` function from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/)). Then make the tree from the sorted result (see these [code examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorted-array-to-balanced-bst/) for this part).

As all steps are could be done in `Theta(n)`, the final result would be in `Theta(n)`, too.